# Jquery libraries not working properly in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

guys i have include two script tags in my application header for datepicker in my form. When i include these tags datepicker function works properly but css for responsive not working. But when i remove these scripts then responsive css working properly but datepicker function stop working.Here below scripts tags as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

When i remove these tags then calender for datepicker not appear but when i remove these then responsive works fine.For responsive i have use two libraries as shown below

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js" rel="javascript" type= "text/js">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" rel="javascript" type= "text/js">
```

Kindly suggest me what i should do. I am using rails 4.Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try not including both jQuery and jQuery min. Choose only one.

Either (Preferred):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Or:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" rel="javascript" type= "text/js">
```

See if it solves your issue. I'm not sure but two jQuery libraries included can be a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the correct rails tags:

In your application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

In your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require other_libraries
```

Try to use gems like this to solve your problems:

[Boostrap Datepicker Rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)